# Parity transformation of spin-3/2 field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors

In conventional quantum field theory textbook, we can find the expression of parity transformation of spin-0, 1/2 or 1 fields. For example, for spin-1/2 fields, we have 
$$U^{-1}(\mathcal{P})\Psi(x) U(\mathcal{P})=i\gamma^0\Psi(\mathcal{P}x)$$
in $D=4$. I know the expression for parity transformation of spin-0, 1/2 or 1 fields. Unfortunately, in most of the references that I can find, they did not mention how spin-3/2 fields are transformed.

Problem 5.2 of Weinberg's QFT Volume.1 exactly addressed my concern, but Weinberg is generally known as an advanced text in QFT, I might not have time to go through everything. An answer to Problem 5.2 will break the biggest obstacle that I am facing.

My proposition: since spacetime indices transform through multiplying a rank-2 representation tensor and spinor indices transformed like "multiplying a matrix", I suppose:
$$U^{-1}(\mathcal{P})\psi_{a\mu}(x)U(\mathcal{P})=\mathcal{P}_\mu{ }^\nu D_a{ }^b\psi_{b\nu}(\mathcal{P}x)$$
where $a,b$ are spinor indices and $\mu,\nu$ are spacetime indices. $D$ is some matrix of the nature like $i\gamma^0$ in the case of spin-1/2 and I don't know what it's like.

I really hope somebody can suggest some references on the topic or point out whether my proposition is correct. If it is correct, I hope to have the expression "$D$".